# Win32 unhandled exception when inheriting from dependency object and declaring the properties in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I face win32 unhandled exception in UWP when I use a model which inherits from a base class which in turn inherits from a dependency object.

[image: Win32 Unhandled Exception - link for exception image]

I define the property in xaml as the follow code.

Codes

```
public abstract class BaseModel : DependencyObject    
{
...
}

public class MainModel : BaseModel    
{

// Dependency Property
public bool ShowLabel

{      

    get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowLabelProperty); }

    set { SetValue(ShowLabelProperty, value); }

}

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowLabelProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowLabel", typeof(bool), typeof(MyModel), new PropertyMetadata(false));
...
}
```

Sample level declaration of the Model

```
<mycontrol:MyModel ShowLabel="True" />
```

If I define any property in the model it creates this issue.

**Sample Link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aml_7nNZeX6ka7-sLQtjaUb_7a4**

Regards,

Samuel

Comment: I think you should give all the code that I can run your code.

Comment: I could not locate the problem by your segment code. Could you provide more detail about your requirement.

Comment: Hi All,

I have added the sample link.